# Имитация ввода текста

Tags: jquery

В данном коде текст вставляется в форму сразу весь. Как сделать что-то на подобии `animate()`, чтобы пользователь видел как в форме печатается автоматически текст?

```js
$('input').val('New Text');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962256/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-typed-js/962269#962269

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Переход на новую строку typed.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962256/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-typed-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если туда нужно равномерно печатать текст, без пауз и т.п., можно так:

```js
(function(){

let text = ('New Text about Lorem ipsum dolor ame...').split('');
//Строчку превратили в массив. Каждый отдельный символ - отдельный элемент.
let bubu = document.getElementById('bubu');

for( let i = 0; i < text.length; i++ ){
  setTimeout( function(){
    bubu.value += text[i];
  }, i*100); 
  // Цикл-то срабатывает сразу, а поставленный таймаут зависит от значения i
  // На каждом круге - будет больше.
}

console.log( String(text) );

})();
```

```html
<input id="bubu" type="text" style="width: 400px;">
```